# PNG or JPEG of a single colour not returning via REST API

Tags: java, rest, io, png, inputstream

I've implemented a Spring Boot application which returns images from GET requests to a getimage API, and it works fine for images that have varying content, but not for cases where the image is a single colour. I can see on the file system that the image is fine, it just won't return.

A genericised version of the code for returning the images is as follows:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> getImage(String pathToFile, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

    if (new File(pathToFile).exists()){
        try {
            response.setContentType("image/png");
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(pathToFile);
            IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("ERROR", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The response headers etc. from a SUCCESSFUL request (taken from JMeter):

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2016-03-02 15:51:26 GMT
Load time: 2044
Connect Time: 1
Latency: 4
Size in bytes: 310323
Headers size in bytes: 150
Body size in bytes: 310173
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 200
Response message: OK

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: image/png;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 02 Mar 2016 15:51:26 GMT


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: image/png;charset=UTF-8
DataEncoding: UTF-8
```

The response headers from a FAILED request, with the single colour image:

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2016-03-02 16:24:44 GMT
Load time: 5
Connect Time: 1
Latency: 5
Size in bytes: 2056
Headers size in bytes: 2056
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 200
Response message: OK

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Accept-Charset: big5, big5-hkscs, euc-jp, euc-kr, gb18030, gb2312, gbk, ibm-thai, ibm00858, ibm01140, ibm01141, ibm01142, ibm01143, ibm01144, ibm01145, ibm01146, ibm01147, ibm01148, ibm01149, ibm037, ibm1026, ibm1047, ibm273, ibm277, ibm278, ibm280, ibm284, ibm285, ibm290, ibm297, ibm420, ibm424, ibm437, ibm500, ibm775, ibm850, ibm852, ibm855, ibm857, ibm860, ibm861, ibm862, ibm863, ibm864, ibm865, ibm866, ibm868, ibm869, ibm870, ibm871, ibm918, iso-2022-cn, iso-2022-jp, iso-2022-jp-2, iso-2022-kr, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-13, iso-8859-15, iso-8859-2, iso-8859-3, iso-8859-4, iso-8859-5, iso-8859-6, iso-8859-7, iso-8859-8, iso-8859-9, jis_x0201, jis_x0212-1990, koi8-r, koi8-u, shift_jis, tis-620, us-ascii, utf-16, utf-16be, utf-16le, utf-32, utf-32be, utf-32le, utf-8, windows-1250, windows-1251, windows-1252, windows-1253, windows-1254, windows-1255, windows-1256, windows-1257, windows-1258, windows-31j, x-big5-hkscs-2001, x-big5-solaris, x-compound_text, x-euc-jp-linux, x-euc-tw, x-eucjp-open, x-ibm1006, x-ibm1025, x-ibm1046, x-ibm1097, x-ibm1098, x-ibm1112, x-ibm1122, x-ibm1123, x-ibm1124, x-ibm1364, x-ibm1381, x-ibm1383, x-ibm300, x-ibm33722, x-ibm737, x-ibm833, x-ibm834, x-ibm856, x-ibm874, x-ibm875, x-ibm921, x-ibm922, x-ibm930, x-ibm933, x-ibm935, x-ibm937, x-ibm939, x-ibm942, x-ibm942c, x-ibm943, x-ibm943c, x-ibm948, x-ibm949, x-ibm949c, x-ibm950, x-ibm964, x-ibm970, x-iscii91, x-iso-2022-cn-cns, x-iso-2022-cn-gb, x-iso-8859-11, x-jis0208, x-jisautodetect, x-johab, x-macarabic, x-maccentraleurope, x-maccroatian, x-maccyrillic, x-macdingbat, x-macgreek, x-machebrew, x-maciceland, x-macroman, x-macromania, x-macsymbol, x-macthai, x-macturkish, x-macukraine, x-ms932_0213, x-ms950-hkscs, x-ms950-hkscs-xp, x-mswin-936, x-pck, x-sjis_0213, x-utf-16le-bom, x-utf-32be-bom, x-utf-32le-bom, x-windows-50220, x-windows-50221, x-windows-874, x-windows-949, x-windows-950, x-windows-iso2022jp
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 02 Mar 2016 16:24:44 GMT


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
DataEncoding: UTF-8
```

The empty body of the failed request seems to suggest that the InputStream/IOUtils execution has not worked correctly. Let me know if I've forgotten to include anything.

**EDIT:** I opened the problematic non-returning image in an image editor and draw a squiggle across it - IT NOW DOWNLOADS PERFECTLY. The issue is definitely with IOUtils copying the stream for a single colour image, but why?

I have narrowed it down to the bizarre circumstances of: If the image is 8kb, it does not get returned. If it is resized so that it is 9kb+, it returns successfully. Is there a minimum buffer or something in IOUtils.copy?

Comment: you're getting this response because file you're requesting does not exist or not accessible because of permissions

Comment: The file is definitely there, I can see it in the file system and subsequent tests have shown that the "if file exists" section of the code is being executed.

It also can't be a permissions thing because the other image that returned successfully is in the same folder.

The problem does definitely seem to be that IOUtils.copy is not doing its job, but why would a single colour image affect that?

Comment: change `return new ResponseEntity<String>("", HttpStatus.OK);` to `return new ResponseEntity<String>(pathToFile+" does not exist", HttpStatus.OK);`

Comment: Can anyone solve the <8kb issue I described in the edited post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by setting the content length explicitly in the header:

```
File actualFile = new File(pathToFile);
if (actualFile.exists()){
    try {
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(actualFile.length()));
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(pathToFile);
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        ...
    }
}
```

This is an earlier version of a question I asked here: [Response fails to return image when outputBuffer bytesWritten < 8kb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314082/response-fails-to-return-image-when-outputbuffer-byteswritten-8kb)

Can be closed as duplicate.