# Response fails to return image when outputBuffer bytesWritten < 8kb

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, httpresponse, outputstream

Within a SpringBoot app, I am attempting to return images via a Response object's outputBuffer, via:

```
try {
    response.setContentType("image/png");
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(pathToFile);
    IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());

}
catch (Exception e){
    ...
}
```

This works fine, **unless the image is less than 8kb**, in which case it just returns nothing.

Can anyone tell me why being less than 8kb would cause the Response to actually return zero data (and - crucially - how to remedy this)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by setting the content length explicitly in the header:

```
File actualFile = new File(pathToFile);
if (actualFile.exists()){
    try {
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(actualFile.length()));
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(pathToFile);
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        ...
    }
}
```

I guess it didn't like not knowing the size of the content if it was below 8kb.